# Showing that $A\rightarrowtail A \times \{x\}$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$A\rightarrowtail A \times \{x\}$ where $A$ is any set and $\{x\}$ is an arbitrary one-object set.

How would I show the following is a bijection ( one to one and onto)?

I know if I turn it into a function I get

$f:A\rightarrow A\times \{x\}$

Which means if $a\in A$ then $f(a)=(a,x)$

But how would you show one to one and the onto?

Comment: you probably mean $A\times\{x\}$

Comment: yes sorry I get this notation mixed up

Comment: There is an easy bijection from $A$ to $A \times \{x\}$ . Try it by your own :)

Comment: show that if f(a)=f(b) then a=b. So f is injective. Show that for an tuple (a,x) there is a y from A such that f(y)=(a,x) (What is the value of y?).So f is surjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any arbitrary element $a\in A$, and take any one-element set $\{x\}$ and let $f_x(a) = (a, x)$.

So $f_x(A) = \{(a, x)\mid a\in A, x\in \{x\}\}$.

Note, this $x\in \{x\}$ must be the same $x$ in all ordered pairs $(a,x)\in A\times \{x\}$, else $f$ is not a function.

You can show that $f_x$ is bijective by proving it has an inverse $f_x^{-1}(a, x) = a$.

Comment: I see that makes sense so {x} means set of x. then $x\in\{x\}$ that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, $\{x\}$ is the set containing a single element, $x$.

Comment: You had a good start, Fernando. I am puzzled by the down-votes you received: You always show effort!

Answer (score 2):

The alphabet $x$ inside $\{x\}$ is fixed so if $a=b$ where $a,b\in A$ then, $$(a,x)=(b,x).$$ This proofs that $f$ is a well-defined function. Now, assume that $(a,x)=(b,x)$ so $a=b$and therefore $f$ is one-one function. If $a\in A$ then $f(a)=(a,x)\in A\times\{x\}$ and so $f$ is onto.